# many to many mapping between two tables of different projects of distributed database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, distributed-system

I am creating a data-model where i am using many-many relation but thing is we are using distributed database and mapping between two tables which is created in same database but from different projects.

For example two tables `member` and `subscription` and database `abc` but `member` table created by project `abc` and `subscription` table created by `xyz` project and i want mapping between `member` and `subscription` tables in project `xyz`. I am coder of `xyz` project.

[image: dm]

**subscription entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode( callSuper = false )
@EntityListeners( AuditingEntityListener.class )
@Table( name = "subscription" )
public class Subscription
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Setter( AccessLevel.PROTECTED )
    @Column( name = "sub_id" )
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinTable( name = "membersubscription", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "sub_id" ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "m_id" ) } )
    private List<MemberSubscription> memberIds1;// i want to map with member table which is created by different project but in same database.


    //other columns

}
```

Comment: What is the problem if you use the same database? You need to make a bridge table to define the many to many relation.

Comment: Ideally, classes in project `xyz` should not access table created by project `abc` directly. Instead `abc` project should provided `API` using which `xyz` project will access tables created by `abc`

Comment: Your diagram seems correct for the most part, except `Member` to `member_subscription` and `subscription` to `member_subscription` relationships should end up being `1-to-many`. Since that is the case I do not understand the problem/question.

Comment: @NiVeR my problem is that i can't make table from project `xyz`. I want to know can i make many to many mapping without using `@Entity or @Table` in `member` entity.

Comment: post your entities.

Comment: @BillyFrost Please check edited question.